# Xpath Expression to get immediate and non-leaf children

Tags: xpath

i'd like to have an xpath expression to get only all immediate and non-leaf children of a node.

When i run the expression for such an XML tree:

```
<root>
<attribute1>a</attribute1>
<attribute2>b</attribute2>
<attribute3>c</attribute3>  
<ElementA>
    <ElementB>
        <ElementC>AC</ElementC>
    </ElementB>
</ElementA>
<ElementX>
    <ElementB1>
        <ElementC1>C1</ElementC1>
    </ElementB1>
</ElementX>
<Other>
    <ElementB2>B2</ElementB2>
</Other>
<NewOne>
    <ElementB3>
        <ElementC3>
            <ElementC4>C4</ElementC4>
        </ElementC3>
    </ElementB3>
</NewOne>
 </root>
```

I should get ElementA, ElementX, Other, NewOne.

Thans for any help.

Comment: Why did you tag this [java]?

Comment: It's a mistake : that's because i use a java program to browse the xml tree.

Answer (score 4):

This would be:

```
/root/*[*]
```

(the predicate is there to make sure that selected nodes have at least one child)